# How to get a proper SVG code

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I've been trying to create some SVG drawing animations like this:
[SVG animation](http://codepen.io/MyXoToD/blog/howto-self-drawing-svg-animation)

The problem I encounter however is how to get a proper SVG code for that. Let's say I have a png drawing and I want to convert it to SVG. When I use Inkscape I get something like this which is useless.

```
xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcG
```

Online tools like this one: [SVG converter](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg)
are little bit better because they output something like this:

```
path d="M3875 6730 c-38 -7 -902 -134 -1130 -166 -22 -3 -51 -7 -65 -9 -14
```

I thought that it's gonna work but I was wrong. It won't animate.
How do I get a proper SVG code like in these [examples](http://codepen.io/MyXoToD/blog/howto-self-drawing-svg-animation)?

Comment: You can't convert bitmap images into vector. There are some tools, though, that does that, like Corel Draw Trace Tool, but don't expect them to do magic.

Comment: Did you try illustrator exported svg. It is very simplified and you will get path easily.

Comment: The result from SVG converter is the way to go. With paths and other SVG objects available you can go ahead and script your animation. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeap I tried Illustrator and it also outputs this base64 gibberish. I guess I just need to create vector images from scratch.

Comment: I basically substituted the code from SVG converter and placed in this example from the link I provided. It just doesn't display. Give me a moment I'l put it on jsfiddle

Comment: Code from example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/przemoo83/xgouy6vb/
The same code with my converted SVG that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/przemoo83/aoay9mmj/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may first learn how svg works. Then you'll understand that convert a PNG to a SVG is not that simple.

Anyway, if you've got a real SVG (you were already mentioning something with a `<path>`, you can animate it.

### Draw your SVG

First, you need an SVG. Here is one with a simple path, drawing a crossed square:

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: none; stroke: black">
  <path d="M 10,10 l 100,0 l 0,100 l -100,0 l 0,-100 l 100,100 M 110,10 l -100,100" />
</svg>
```

### Animate it

To animate a path, we'll use a combination of two properties:

- `stroke-dasharray`: makes our path dashed, and defined the width of dashes and whitespaces
- `stroke-dashoffset`: offsets our path

Basically, we'll create a dash as long as our path (or even longer), and add a high offset to make it invisible. Then we'll animate this offset to make it visible progressively:

[image]

```css
svg {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000px;
  -webkit-animation: draw 5s;
  animation: draw 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1000px; } 
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; } 
}
@keyframes draw {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1000px; } 
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; } 
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: none; stroke: black">
  <path d="M 10,10 l 100,0 l 0,100 l -100,0 l 0,-100 l 100,100 l 0,-100 l -100,100" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the right way to do a svg is with Adobe Illustrator. From there you can save an svg file with the proper svg code.

Comment: Ok I basically understand that I need to do it properly from the beginning. But anyone can explain why this doesn't work?:
http://jsfiddle.net/przemoo83/aoay9mmj/  this is svg I used http://one.ct8.pl/

Comment: The problem is that you used this svg file which you converted fron png if I got it ok? You should make png file from svg. And the problem with online tools is that they convert files and then you get the code like the one in your jsfiddle and it doesn't work. I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

on my website [www.stretchsketch.com](http://www.stretchsketch.com) you can view multiple customizable svg models. Most of these models are created with iPath, a javascript libray for formalizing line drawings (also backyard engineered). Having a model in iPath lets you export it to svg (paths) or DXF which is more useful for cnc shops (the primary use case of this whole project.

I'm working on animation (customizing on a timeline).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: none; stroke: black">
  <path d="M 10,10 l 100,0111 l 0,100 l -100,0 l 0,-100 l 100,100 M 110,10 l -100,100" />
</svg>
```